# JavaFX CSS URL isn't loading

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to load an XML Resource, and I am doing it like this:

```
fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Document.fxml").openStream());
```

When I run my code I then get this error:

```
null/../css/button.css
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path:23
```

When I look at line 23 I have this:

```
<URL value="@../css/button.css" />
```

this works:

```
fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Document.fxml"));
```

but then when I run the following

```
controller = (DocumentController)fxmlLoader.getController();
```

`controller` is `null`

How can I fix the css issue?

Comment: Do you have the `fx:controller` defined in your `Document.fxml` ?

Comment: Yes: `<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1200.0" styleClass="anchor-pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="phantom.DocumentController">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but I think the issue is that you're providing an input stream to the `FXMLLoader` instead of a `URL`. Because of this, the `FXMLLoader` is unaware of the location of the `FXML` resource, and hence it can't resolve the `..` in the URL tag. This would explain the error message:

> null/../css/button.css
>
> javafx.fxml.LoadException:
>
> unknown path:23

The path you provided is relative to `null` because the FXMLLoader doesn't know the location of the FXML file; notice also it reports "unknown path" as the source of the FXML.

Try this (which is more common anyway)

```
fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Document.fxml"));
root = fxmlLoader.load();
```

I'm figuring it returns null for the controller only because there was an error in loading the fxml.

Comment: It seems that, that is the issue. It doesn't show null anymore!

Comment: The way I had it was from someone else's answer. Thanks for the Answer!

Answer (score 0):

In your .fxml, change `<URL value = "@../css/button.css"/>` to `<URL value = "@/css/button.css" />`. It's the same if you had "css" or "image".